# Firebase connecting with simulator but not in real device iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am developing a app which has the connection with Firebase DB. This is one part of my code,

```
let ref1 = Database.database().reference()
ref1.child("UserId").child("\(user_id)").setValue(["name": "\(name)"])
```

And this one is working fine in simulator(updating value in firebase DB), but not in real device. I have tried some solutions from this site, still I can't get the output.

Is anyone there to help me?

Comment: Are you logged? Can you try to change the rules on firebase with a write = true to check if it's a auth issue.

Comment: @Kerberos I have already changed the rule write = true

Answer (score 2):

This could be because you are not authenticated on your device or any other reasons. In order to debug it, I suggest you to add a completion block for your `setValue` which is going to be called whenever the write has been committed to the database. If the call was unsuccessful for any reasons, you can get the error object and take a look at the error.

```
yourRef.setValue(["name": "\(name)"]) { (error, dbRef) in
   if (error != nil) {
     //catch the error here 
     print("Data could not be saved.")
   } else {
      print("Data saved successfully!")
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your solution, but it's not even entering into the completion block.

Answer (score 0):

At last, the issue was the real device's date and time. The date and time was incorrect in my device. So, the connection with firebase DB failed. Now, it's fixed. Thanks for you suggestions!!